# Scraping PDF from iframe into R

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text of U.N. Security Council (UNSC) resolutions into R. The U.N. maintains an online archive of all UNSC resolutions in PDF format ([here](http://www.un.org/en/sc/documents/resolutions/)). So, in theory, this should be do-able.

If I click on the hyperlink for a specific year and then click on the link for a specific document (e.g., [this one](http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/2341(2017))), I can see the PDF in my browser. When I try to download that PDF by pointing `download.file` at the link in the URL bar, it seems to work. When I try to read the contents of that file into R using the `pdf_text` function from the `pdftools` package, however, I get a stack of error messages.

Here's what I'm trying that's failing. If you run it, you'll see the error messages I'm talking about.

```
library(pdftools)
pdflink <- "http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/2341(2017)"
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file(pdflink, tmp, mode = "wb")
doc <- pdf_text(tmp)
```

What am I missing? I *think* it has to do with the link addresses to the downloadable versions of these files differing from the link addresses for the in-browser display, but I can't figure out how to get the path to the former. I tried right-clicking on the download icon; using the "Inspect" option in Chrome to see the URL identified as 'src' there ([this link](https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N17/038/57/PDF/N1703857.pdf?OpenElement)); and pointing the rest of my process at it. Again, the `download.file` part executes, but I get the same error messages when I run `pdf_text`. I also tried a) varying the `mode` part of the call to `download.file` and b) tacking ".pdf" onto the end of the path to `tmp`, but neither of those helped.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Can you open the file after you've downloaded it with `download.file()`?

Comment: @MrFlick, the stack of error messages starts with `error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)`, includes a bunch of "illegal character" messages, and ends with `Error: PDF parsing failure.`

Comment: I tried your code and the pdf file downloaded was corrupted. When I try the said link in browser it gives some error there as well. Is the link correct?

Comment: @anonR, yes, the link is correct. If I copy it from the code above and paste it in the url bar in Chrome, I get the page displaying the PDF of the relevant resolution.

Comment: @MrFlick, to answer your other question: yes. If I manually download the file using the download button on the toolbar on the page with the url shown in my code and point `pdf_text` at that file, it reads fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pdf you are looking to download is in an iframe in the main page, so the link you are downloading only contains html. 
You need to follow the link in the iframe to get the actual link to the pdf. You need to jump to several pages to get cookies/temporary urls before getting to the direct link to download the pdf.

Here's an example for the link you posted:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(rvest)
library(pdftools)

s <- html_session("http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/2341(2017)")
#get the link in the mainFrame iframe holding the pdf
frame_link <- s %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//frame[@name='mainFrame']") %>%
  html_attr("src")

#go to that link
s <- s %>% jump_to(url=frame_link)

#there is a meta refresh with a link to another page, get it and go there
temp_url <- s %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("meta") %>%
  html_attr("content") %>% {gsub(".*URL=","",.)} 

s <- s %>% jump_to(url=temp_url)

#get the LtpaToken cookie then come back
s %>% jump_to(url="https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/prod/ods_mother.nsf?Login&Username=freeods2&Password=1234") %>%
  back() 

#get the pdf link and download it
pdf_link <- s %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']") %>%
  html_attr("content") %>% {gsub(".*URL=","",.)}

s <- s %>% jump_to(pdf_link)
tmp <- tempfile()
writeBin(s$response$content,tmp)
doc <- pdf_text(tmp)
doc
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, to iterate it over the umpteen resolutions of the past half-century...